# margin-left, margin-right does not work in Android Browser

Tags: html, android-browser

Consider this code below:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; text-align: center;">
    <button style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">This is a button</button>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I tried to run it in Chrome and Mozilla, it produces the output below:

[image]

However, when I tried to run it in android browser, the button is in the LEFT side, seems like margin-left and margin-right doesnt work on the android browser. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refresh your browser a few times, it must've cached the css. It looks the way you expect on android 4.4.

To Clear cache on chrome for android:

1. Touch Chrome menu > Settings.
2. Touch (Advanced) Privacy.
3. Touch Clear browsing data.

If it still does not work with my demo then let me know what version and browser you're using on android.

UPDATE: (for those wondering)
This was solved by adding a width to the element that is being centered. In order for margin:auto; to work on some old browsers, in this case we added width:auto;

Demo to test http://jsfiddle.net/Lw543yys/.
    <>
[image]

```
        <>
```

Comment: Im using Android 4.2, I refreshed the page several times but it didn't worked!

Comment: Here's what I did: I clear the data of the Android Browser and forced it to stop but still didnt worked!

Comment: Are you using chrome for android?

Comment: No. Just the default browser.

Comment: hmmm. it worked in jsfidlle but why not in my android phone?

Comment: In those old browsers you have to define a width on the button for margin auto to work. I added: width:auto;   Try that in your code. Please mark mine as answer.

Comment: @Hanoncs, you should post this as an answer so that you may be acknowledge!

Comment: I just have to ask, Hanoncs, what is up with the `<>` at the end? lol

Comment: Ok xD That makes sense I guess.

Comment: @Hanoncs, I dont see any check mark, you must post it as an answer.

Comment: It is above the picture I posted, next to the 2 points, these are just comments on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using "reset.css" (or) "normalize.css"

I used one https://code.google.com/p/reset5/

which will fix browser issues across multiple browsers

You can also use http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

then your CSS will behave properly in all browsers